# How to pass arguments to hyperfine in rust

Tags: rust

I am able to run my main function with the following `cargo` command. It has three arguments.

`cargo run --release --example cover_types 1 0.1 0.1`

But, I couldn't run the following hyperfine command:

`hyperfine --runs 3 .\target\release\examples\cover_types 1 0.1 0.1`

I tried the following but none of them worked.

`hyperfine --runs 3 .\target\release\examples\cover_types -- 1 0.1 0.1`

`hyperfine --runs 3 .\target\release\examples\cover_types -L 1 0.1 0.1`

How can I run the hyperfine command with arguments?

Comment: Just quote the command with its arguments?

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

try with `/` in-place of `\`

```
hyperfine --runs 3 ./target/release/examples/cover_types 1 0.1 0.1
```

Comment: I am on windows…

Comment: hmm i though mac and windows issue 1st . ok then .i edit with more if got .

Comment: did you check installation status of `hyperfine `  ? you can check this by `hyperfine --version`